# problem after upgrading laravel and php version

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I was working on laravel 5.2.45 and PHP 7.1 without any problem, then I decided to upgrade to laravel 7 and php 7.4
the project which I working on is working but I have problems with some pages especially with the belongs to relation in laravel , I get this error

```
 [2021-02-13 15:32:00] local.ERROR: Trying to access array offset on value of type null {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to access array offset on value of type null at /var/www/html/easy/app/Http/Controllers/SubscriberController.php:431)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/easy/app/Http/Controllers/SubscriberController.php(431): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError()
#1 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\SubscriberController->userFilterData()
#2 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array()
#3 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction()
#4 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(240): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#5 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(197): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#6 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(681): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#7 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#8 /var/www/html/easy/app/Http/Middleware/Permissions.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#9 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): App\\Http\\Middleware\\Permissions->handle()
#10 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(76): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#11 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#12 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#13 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#14 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#15 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#16 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#17 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#18 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#19 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#20 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#21 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(683): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#22 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#23 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(624): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#24 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(613): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#25 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#26 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#27 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#28 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle()
#29 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#30 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(140): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#31 /var/www/html/easy/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(109): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#32 /var/www/html/easy/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#33 {main}
"}
```

this is the Model that I have

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subscriber extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reign_users';

    public $timestamps = false;

    /*public function profile()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Profile', 'owner');
    }*/
    public function profiles()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Profile', 'id', 'srvid');
    }

    public function owners()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\AclManager', 'id', 'owner');
    }
    
    public function radAcctData() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\RadAcct', 'username', 'username');
    }
    
    public function usermac() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\UserMAC', 'username', 'username');
    }
    
    public function onlineData() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\OnlineUser', 'username', 'username');
    }

    public function userInvoice(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\UserInvoice', 'username', 'username')->latest();
    }

    public function userNetwork(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Networks', 'id', 'networkid');
    }

    public function thanaName(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Thana', 'id', 'thana');
    }


}
```

and this is my code in controller code

```
  public function userFilterData(Request $request) {


        $user = Subscriber::with( 'userInvoice', 'usermac', 'userNetwork');

//        $user = Subscriber::leftJoin('radacct as r', function ($join) use($request) {
//                    $join->on('r.username', '=', 'reign_users.username');
//                    $join->on("r.acctstoptime", "IS", DB::raw("NULL"));
//                })
//                        ->with('userInvoice', 'usermac', 'userNetwork');

        /* only manager cannot see the deleted user */
        if (Session::get('type') == "Manager" && Session::get('admin_assistant') == 0) {
            $user->where('reign_users.owner', Session::get('id'));
        }

//date filter conditionn
        if (isset($request->dateFlag)) {
            $today = date("Y-m-d");
            if ($request->dateFlag == 1) {
                $user->where(DB::raw("date_format(reign_users.createdon, '%Y-%m-%d')"), $today);
            } elseif ($request->dateFlag == 2) {
                $weekStart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 days'));
                $user->whereRaw("date_format(reign_users.createdon, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$weekStart' AND '$today'");
            } elseif ($request->dateFlag == 3) {
                $monthStart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of this month'));
                $user->whereRaw("date_format(reign_users.createdon, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$monthStart' AND '$today'");
            } elseif ($request->dateFlag == 4) {
                $range = explode('-', $request->dateRange);
                $startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($range[0]));
                $endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($range[1]));
                $user->whereRaw("date_format(reign_users.createdon, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'");
            } else {

            }
        }


//filter by user's status like active,online,expired
        if (isset($request->userStatus) && $request->userStatusVal != "") {
            $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            if ($request->userStatusVal == 1) {
                $user->whereRaw("reign_users.expiration <= '$today'");
            }
            if ($request->userStatusVal == 2) {
                $user->whereRaw("reign_users.expiration >= '$today'");
            }
            if ($request->userStatusVal == 3) {
                $threeDaysAfter = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+3 days"));
                $dateToday = date("Y-m-d");
                $user->whereRaw("date_format(reign_users.expiration, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '$dateToday' AND '$threeDaysAfter'");
            }
            if ($request->userStatusVal == 4) {
                $user->whereRaw("reign_users.enableuser = 1");
            }
            if ($request->userStatusVal == 5) {
                $user->whereRaw("reign_users.enableuser = 0");
            }
        }

        if (isset($request->createdBy) && $request->createdByVal != "") {
            $user->whereRaw("reign_users.createdby = $request->createdByVal");
        }

        if (isset($request->profile) && $request->profileVal != "") {
            $user->whereRaw("reign_users.srvid = $request->profileVal");
        }

        if (isset($request->manager) && $request->managerVal != "") {
            $user->whereRaw("reign_users.owner = $request->managerVal");
        }

        if (isset($request->network) && $request->networkVal != "") {
            $user->whereRaw("reign_users.networkid = $request->networkVal");
        }

        if (($request->order[0]['column'] == 0) && isset($request->order[0]['dir'])) {
            $order = $request->order[0]['dir'];
            $user->orderBy("reign_users.username", $order);
        }

        if (($request->order[0]['column'] == 4) && isset($request->order[0]['dir'])) {
            $order = $request->order[0]['dir'];
            $user->orderBy("reign_users.expiration", $order);
        }

        if (($request->order[0]['column'] == 5) && isset($request->order[0]['dir'])) {
            $order = $request->order[0]['dir'];
            $user->orderBy("reign_users.extended_expiration", $order);
        }
        if (($request->order[0]['column'] == 6) && isset($request->order[0]['dir'])) {
            $order = $request->order[0]['dir'];
            $user->orderBy("reign_users.owner", $order);
        }

        /* string search */
        $searchStr = $request->search['value'];
        if ($searchStr != "") {
            $user->whereRaw("(reign_users.username like '%$searchStr%' OR reign_users.firstname like '%$searchStr%' OR reign_users.lastname like '%$searchStr%' OR reign_users.mobile like '%$searchStr%' OR reign_users.mac like '%$searchStr%')");
        }

        $user->where('reign_users.status', '!=', 3);


        $data['recordsTotal'] = $user->count();
        $data['recordsFiltered'] = $user->count();

        $user->limit($request->length)->offset($request->start);
        $userData = $user->get();

//        return $userData[1]->onlineData->status;
//        $expiredDate = $userData[1]->expiration;
//        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
//        $expiredInThreeDays = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 days', strtotime($expiredDate)));
////        return $expiredInThreeDays;
//        if ($expiredInThreeDays >= $currentDate) {
//            return $expiredDate;
//        }else{
//            return $currentDate;
//        }

        $data['draw'] = $request->draw;


        $data['data'] = array();
        $sl = 0;
        foreach ($userData as $k => $val) {
            $isNewUser = 0;

            /* only new User don't have any invoice and monthly package user */
            if ($val->userInvoice == null && $val->profiles['timebaseexp'] == 1) {
                $isNewUser = 1;

                if ($val->user_type == 2) {
                    $profileMonthStartDay = $val->custom_month_start_day;
                    $userCurrentExpiration = date($val->expiration);

                    $countMonth = 1;
                    //$newDate = strtotime('+' . $countMonth . ' month', strtotime($userCurrentExpiration));
                    $newDate = strtotime('last day of next month', strtotime($userCurrentExpiration));
                    $nextMonthYear = date('Y-m', $newDate);

                    $settingData = SoftwareSetting::select('value')->where('attribute', 'gnrl_expiration_time')->first();
                    $time = $settingData->value;

                    $activationDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($nextMonthYear . '-' . $profileMonthStartDay . ' ' . $time));
                } else {
                    /* if user have custom month start day, profile month start is ignored */
                    if ($val->custom_month_start_day != null) {
                        $profileMonthStartDay = $val->custom_month_start_day;
                    } else {
                        $profileMonthStartDay = $val->profiles['month_start_day'];
                    }

                    $profileUnitMonth = $val->profiles['timeunitexp'];
                    $userCurrentExpiration = date($val->expiration);


                    //$newDate = strtotime('+' . $countMonth . ' month', strtotime($userCurrentExpiration));
                    $newDate = strtotime('last day of next month', strtotime($userCurrentExpiration));
                    $nextMonthYear = date('Y-m', $newDate);


                    $settingData = SoftwareSetting::select('value')->where('attribute', 'gnrl_expiration_time')->first();
                    $time = $settingData->value;

                    $activationDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($nextMonthYear . '-' . $profileMonthStartDay . ' ' . $time));
                }

                $createdDate = $val->createdon;
                $newExpirationDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($activationDate));

                $activatedDayCount = date_diff(date_create($createdDate), date_create($newExpirationDate));

                $dayCountNewUser = $activatedDayCount->format("%a");
            }

            $expiredDate = $val->expiration;
            $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
            $expiredInThreeDays = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-3 days', strtotime($expiredDate)));
            $userActive = $val->enableuser;
            if ($currentDate > $expiredDate && $userActive == 0) {
                $color = 'gray';
            } elseif ($currentDate > $expiredDate && $userActive == 1) {
                $color = 'red';
            } elseif ($expiredInThreeDays <= $currentDate) {
                $color = 'orange';
            } elseif ($userActive == 0) {
                $color = 'gray';
            } elseif ($userActive == 1) {
                $color = 'blue';
            } else {
                $color = 'black';
            }

            $data['data'][$sl]['user_name'] = "<a class='userShow'  data-toggle='modal'
                                               data-target='#userDetails' href='$val->id'><strong style='color:" . $color . "'>" . $val->username .
                    "</strong></a><br><small class='text-info'>Added: " . date('d,M Y', strtotime($val->createdon)) . "</small>";



            $data['data'][$sl]['full_name'] = $val->firstname . ' ' . $val->lastname .
                    "<br> <small class='text-info'>Phone: " . $val->mobile . "</small>";


            $data['data'][$sl]['profile'] = ($val->user_type == 2) ? $val->ip : $val->profiles['srvname'] . "<br><small class='text-danger'>" .$val->usermac['mac'].
  "</small>";

            if ($val->isNOC == 1) {
                $networkBox = 'NOC';
            } else {
                $networkBox = 0;//$val->userNetwork['name'];
            }
            $data['data'][$sl]['networkBox'] = $networkBox;

            $data['data'][$sl]['billing_date'] = date('d,M Y H:i:s', strtotime($val->expiration));
//            $data['data'][$sl]['billing_date'] = date('d,M Y H:i:s', strtotime($val->expiration)) .
//                    "<br><small class='text-danger'>Last Online: " .
//                    date("d,M Y, H:i", strtotime($val->lastonline)) . "</small>";

            $data['data'][$sl]['expiration'] = "<small>" . date('d,M Y H:i:s', strtotime($val->extended_expiration)) . "</small>";

            $data['data'][$sl]['owner'] = $val->owners['full_name'] == "" ? "Admin" : $val->owners['full_name'];


            $costAmount = 0;
            if ($val->owners['id'] > 0) {
                $profile = AclManagerProfiles::select('cost_amount')->where(array(
                            'manager_id' => $val->owners['id'],
                            'profile_id' => $val->profiles['id'],
                        ))->first();
                $costAmount = isset($profile->cost_amount) ? $profile->cost_amount : 0;
            }

            if ($isNewUser == 1) {
                $unitPrice = round(($dayCountNewUser / 30) * $val->profiles['unitprice']);
                //$data['data'][$sl]['commission'] = $costAmount > 0 ? ($unitPrice - round(($dayCountNewUser / 30) * $costAmount)) : 0;
            } else {
                $unitPrice = $val->profiles['unitprice'];
                //$data['data'][$sl]['commission'] = $costAmount > 0 ? ($unitPrice - $costAmount) : 0;
            }

            $data['data'][$sl]['monthly_bill'] = $unitPrice + $val->additional_cost - $val->discount;


            $data['data'][$sl]['activation'] = "<a class='userActive badge badge-info' data-toggle='modal'
                                               data-target='#expirationExpand' price='$unitPrice' username='$val->username' href='$val->id'>
                                                Pay Bill
                                            </a>";
            if (Session::get('admin_assistant') == 1 && $val->owner > 0) {
                $data['data'][$sl]['activation'] = "";
            }

            $editUrl = URL::to('subscriber' . '/' . $val->id);

            if ($val->status == 0) {
                $data['data'][$sl]['action'] = "<a href='$editUrl' action='GET'>
                                                <i class='icon-pencil text-info'></i>
                                                </a>
                                                 |
                                                <a href='$editUrl' data-method='delete'
                                                data-confirm='Are you sure?  User will be delete.'>
                                                <i class='icon-trash text-danger'></i>
                                                </a>";
            } else {
                $data['data'][$sl]['action'] = "<a href='$editUrl' data-method='delete'
                                                    data-confirm='Are you sure? Do you want to restore this User?'>
                                                <i class='icon-reload text-danger'></i>
                                                </a>";
            }

            $sl++;
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
        die();
    }
```

this is the manager model

```
class AclManager extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'reign_acl_managers';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\AclManager', 'id', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function manager()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\AclGroup', 'id', 'group_id');
    }

}
```

I have 2 tables, one is for super admin and the other one is for manager, I am trying to get the subscribed users and the manager that they belong to, some of the users belong to super admin who is not found in manager table, so the owner of them in the table will be 0,
so when I am trying to get the owner details I get

```
Trying to access array offset on the value of type null
```

in this line

```
 $data['data'][$sl]['owner'] = $val->owners['full_name'] == "" ? "Admin" : $val->owners['full_name'];
```

the problem is same code working fine on an old version of laravel , but not in this new version. I think the problem is with the relationship in the model, but  I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Did you stop to read the upgrade notes for both PHP and Laravel. You jumped a few versions of both, so you would expect to have to at least check the upgrade notes before doing the jump

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? If that is a line of your own code throwing such an error or warning, why not fix your code?

Comment: I want to fix the code , but I don't know what to do , as I said the relation is worked fine with old verion , so I don't know where is the problem is

Comment: this is the erro [2021-02-13 15:40:25] local.ERROR: Trying to access array offset on value of type null {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to access array offset on value of type null at /var/www/html/easy/app/Http/Controllers/CrmController.php:281)
[stacktrace]

Comment: should I change the relation ? managers must belong to parent or they must be parent by them selves  , when I trying to get the supscriber who belongs to super admin  I get this error , because the owner id of them will be 0 , and this id is not found in manager table

Comment: ALWAYS put the **complete error message** into your quesiton. Summaries are normally of no use at all

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updated the question with full error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$val->owners` is `null`.

In older versions of PHP, this error/notice was silently handled by returning `null` whenever you were trying to use the `[]` operator on a `null` variable.

You can test this by running the following code using first PHP 7.3 then PHP 7.4:

```php
<?php
$a = null;
var_dump($a['a']);
```

PHP 7.3 will print `NULL`, while PHP 7.4 will throw the error you mentioned.

When updgrading your PHP version, these kind of errors are somewhat normal because in the past the language used to be a bit too permissive.

LE: The condition `$val->owners['full_name'] == ""` has worked before because `null == ""` evaluates to `true`, you can instead replace it with `!isset($val->owners['full_name'])`

Comment: thank you for your reply , I think you are right , so how can I avoid this error being through

Comment: check the later edit